# AWS CloudFormation Template for Jupyter

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

When reading the instructions for setting up a CloudFormation Template in [*Creating and Using a Jupyter Instance on AWS*](https://d0.awsstatic.com/WWPS/PDF/AWS_Jupyter_Instance_Whitepaper_v6.pdf), I find the following modification difficult.

```
"AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
  "ap-southeast-2" : {"HVM64" : "ami-58facb3b", "HVMG2" : "ami-6cfdcc0f"}
}
```

I've set up an AMI running on Amazon Linux 2 with instance type "c5d.2xlarge".  Which `HVM` (`HVM64`, `HVMG2`, `HVMP2`) should be chosen?

I've read [How do I specify in an AWS Cloudformation template that my t1.micro instances are 64-bit architecture](https://serverfault.com/q/261336/526078), and I've tried searching [the sample CloudFormation template](https://github.com/scicolabs/jupyter-aws/blob/master/jupyter.template#L65-L114) in the linked PDF, but there's no `c5d.2xlarge` in `AWSInstanceType2Arch`.  The [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html) simply say that it's related to the AMI's architechture without further explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `c5d.2xlarge` choose `HVM64`.

The `HVMG2` is for instances of `g2.*` / `g3.*` GPU-optimised family, similarly `HVMP2` is for `p2.*` and `p3.*` families.

However the AMI IDs for *Amazon Linux 2* are different than the above, check this out: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Hope that helps :)